# How to do basic CRUD on local server with Python?

Tags: python, webserver

I just finish setup the SimpleHTTPServer with this code to run local server (in terminal):

```
import SimpleHTTPServer
import SocketServer
import BaseHTTPServer
import os

HOSTNAME = "localhost"

PORT = 8000

HANDLER = SimpleHTTPServer.SimpleHTTPRequestHandler

os.chdir("/Users/Team/Desktop/python server")

httpd = SocketServer.TCPServer((HOSTNAME, PORT), HANDLER)


print "serving at port", PORT
httpd.serve_forever()
```

Now I would like to do the CRUD by creating HTML, Python Script and using SQLite with this local server. Is it possible to do Basic CRUD with this local server? can you please give me some advice? or I'm in a wrong track?

Answer (score 3):

It might be, but it'd be a lot of work and not worth it at all. Use one of the many Python web frameworks - a mini-framework like Flask probably meets your needs.

Comment: Thank you so much ^^ I have read that Flesk is a micro web frame work and etc. Do I still need to run local server and then use flask in my python script? and after I have test my web app with local server, I will bring it into my client server, will it be problems when I do that? Sorry I never use any web frame work before and very newbie to server thing (I'm new to python too ^^")

Comment: No, Flask includes a local server (using Werkzeug, I believe). See the docs - especially the [quickstart](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/quickstart/#quickstart).